# Change Magento subcategory style

Tags: magento

In my e-shop I have two root categories and four subcategories:

```
COMPUTERS
    ibm
    apple
    acer
    asus
MONITORS
```

When printing the names of the products in the computer subcategories, I'd like to add the logo to each product title. How do I know which category each product belongs to? Which file should I edit?

Thanks

Comment: Can someone please edit to format the list and correct spelling?

Comment: Sorry for the grammar, but English is my second language. Maybe this help:
http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/9012/subcat.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Magento template path hints to guess that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better idea is to use some of extensions with Brand management functionality, those are available at Magento Connect. Because Magento products can belong to more than one category.

Answer (score 0):

No need an extension, create a "brand" or "manufacturer" attribute.
Create the images in /skin/frontend/base/default/images/brand/ibm.jpg etc. (you may have to create the brand folder).

Then in your /app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/list.phtml edit the name part to add getSkinUrl()?>/images/brand/getManufacturer() ?>.jpg" alt="getManufacturer() ?>" />